# How can I RANK() OVER PARTITION BY with a WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, ranking-functions

I need to do 2 ranks in a table, one for all rows and one where Total Cum Production is greater than zero.  Is there any way to do that with a Rank Function?

```
SELECT 
       LocationNumber
      ,[Date]
      ,Oil+Gas+Water as [TotalFluid]
      ,sum(Oil + Gas + Water ) over (partition by [LocationNumber] order by [Date] asc) as [CumTotalFluid]
      ,rank() over (partition by [LocationNumber] order by [Date] asc) as TABLE_DAY
      ,rank() over (partition by [LocationNumber] order by [Date] asc WHERE CumTotalFluid > 0) as Prod_DAY

FROM DV
```

Comment: I would spell out the word "Cumulative" in my object names if I were you. ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional logic:

```
SELECT LocationNumber, [Date], (Oil+Gas+Water) as [TotalFluid],
       sum(Oil + Gas + Water ) over (partition by [LocationNumber] order by [Date] asc) as [CumTotalFluid],
       rank() over (partition by [LocationNumber] order by [Date] asc) as TABLE_DAY
       (CASE WHEN CumTotalFluid > 0
             THEN rank() over (partition by [LocationNumber], CASE WHEN CumTotalFluid > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END order by [Date] asc
                              ) 
        END) as Prod_DAY
FROM DV;
```

The outer `case` only returns values where the condition is true.  The `case` in the `partition by` divides the data into two (more) sets, so the ranking is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - I tried your suggestion but I get an error using the expression to calculate [CumTotalFluid] that Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.  Any suggestions on how to get around that?

Comment: @Ryan . . . You need to use a subquery or CTE if that is a calculated field.

Comment: I don't know about those aliases :|